# C: I made a program to sort an array in ascending order and cannot figure the reason for a certain step in the for loops

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am making a program to sort numbers in an array using the bubble sort method in c and I know how to do it but I cannot figure out what the second for loop's `j<n-i-1`subtraction of i from the length of the array is for. It is probably a simple explanation but I cannot for the life of me scramble my small brain for the answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int input[10],swap;
    printf("Input Numbers: ");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",&input[0],&input[1],&input[2],&input[3],&input[4],&input[5],&input[6],&input[7],&input[8],&input[9]);
    int n=10;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n-i-1;j++){
            if(input[j]>input[j+1]){
                swap=input[j];
                input[j]=input[j+1];
                input[j+1]=swap;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Sorted List: {");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(i<9){
            printf("%d, ",input[i]);
        }
        else{
            printf("%d}",input[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How on earth did you write this code if you don't understand how it works? To answer your question, the highest element will move to `input[n-1]` after the first sweep, so it won't need to be considered again. After the second sweep, the second-highest element will be at `input[n-2]`, and so on. After each pass, the number of elements you need to consider decreases by one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the first iteration of the `i` loop, the greatest element is bubbled to the end of the `n` elements in the array. After that, we know the last element is done. So we only need to do the `n-1` remaining elements.

In the second iteration of the `i` loop, the next greatest element is bubbled to the end of the `n-1` elements we were working on. After that, we know the last two elements are done. So we only need to do the `n-2` remaining elements.

This continues, so that in each iteration, we only need to work on `n-i` elements. Since elements `j` and `j+1` are compared, we only need `j` to reach `n-i-2`, *i.e.*, be less than `n-i-1`., as that will give `j+1` up to `n-i-1`. (The number of elements from index `0` to index `n-i-1` is `n-i`.)